# How do I access the oauth2 authenticated user in a Lumen controller?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, lumen

I have followed this excellent tutorial [Building a Web App with Lumen and  OAuth2](http://esbenp.github.io/2015/05/26/lumen-web-api-oauth-2-authentication/) for setting up OAuth2 and Lumen.  Everything is working fine apart from now I want to access the currently authenticated user information/model.

My route correctly posts the supplied information after I have logged in and I can break with Netbeans inside the controller but I am not clear how to get the user from the underlying Auth framework.  I have tried the three methods indicated here [Authentication - Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user) but to no avail.  The lumen logs shows:

```
==== routes.php ====

$app->group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers','prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'oauth'], function($app)
{
    $app->post('info', 'InfoController@send');
}

==== InfoController.php ====
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

// the controllers
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

class InfoController extends Controller{

    /* /api/info methods */

    public function send(Request $request){

        // can iterate over the entire users table but I just
        // want the current user (must be some method through
        // the authentication stack)
        $users = \App\Auth\User::all();

        foreach ($users as $user) {
           $name = $user->name;
           $key = $user->getAuthIdentifier();
           $pwd = $user->getAuthPassword();
        }

        // CODE GETS HERE BUT how to get the current user?
        // Authenticated OK (request supplies "Access-Token: Bearer ...")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the cleanest solution and may not match your requirements exactly but it does retrieve the user.

I decided to make another DB query in the proxy to get the user with the same key (in my case, email address) that was requested by the client.

In my case I was sending the user id along with the standard oauth token.

You could use the same technique to set some value in the session.

```
// ../app/Auth/Proxy.php
namespace App\Auth;

use App\User;   //     -----    added this line 
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class Proxy {

...

   private function proxy($grantType, array $data = [])
   {
      ...

      $response = json_decode($guzzleResponse->getBody());

      if (property_exists($response, "access_token")) {
         ...
        // added the following line to get the user
        $user = User::where('email',$data['username'])->get()->first();
        // untested, but you could add the user to your session here
        $request = app()->make('request');
        $request->session()->put('current_user', $user);

        $response = [
                'accessToken'            => $response->access_token,
                'accessTokenExpiration'  => $response->expires_in,
                'userId'                 => $user->id,
        ];
    }
 ...
```